# How can array name be empty string?

Tags: tcl

The following statement in TCL man page perplexed me about TCL array:

> $name(index)  Name gives the name of an array variable and index gives
>   the name of an element  within that array. Name must contain only
>   letters, digits, underscores, and namespace  separators, ***and may be
>   an empty string***.

I wonder how the array name be an empty string?

Here are my experiments:

```
% set a ""
% set ${a}(1) 100
can't set "(1)": variable isn't array
% set (1) 100
can't set "(1)": variable isn't array
% set $a(1) 100
can't read "a(1)": variable isn't array
% set {}(1) 100
extra characters after close-brace
```

Can you show me the way how to create an array whose name is empty string?

Comment: The empty name is legal, but if we could we'd rewind time and make it not be so. It's just that by the time we thought of this case, it was in use in the wild. So instead we documented it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you already set variable with empty name to some value. You got errors because variable exists and it not array. Use:

```
unset -nocomplain ""
set (foo) bar
```

or

```
unset -nocomplain ""
array set "" [list foo bar]
```

Comment: and then, for completeness, `puts $(foo)`